# File uploads to asp.net web api using pure javascript via ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to do file uploads through `ajax` to my web api. My server side codes prove to be working cause I have managed to post files using a debugging Fiddler and it works fine. But I am failing to write successful javascript code that will be able to do the upload.

Below is my html code:

```js
function sendImage() {
  var data = new FormData();
  var file = document.getElementById('upload').files[0];

  data.append("image",file);
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp_br=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp_br=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp_br.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp_br.readyState == 4 ) {
      var data = xmlhttp_br.responseText;
      alert(xmlhttp_br.status+" "+data);
      var file = JSON.parse(data);
    }
  }  

  xmlhttp_br.open("POST","http://localhost:59103/"+"api/upload/testUpload",true);
  xmlhttp_br.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
  xmlhttp_br.setRequestHeader("filename", file.name);
  xmlhttp_br.send(data);
}
```

```html
<input name="UploadedImage" id="upload" type="file"  accept="image/*">
<button onclick="sendImage()"> Upload Image </button>
<img id ="image">
```

My `c#` server side code is as follows

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostFile()
{
  HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
  if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
  {
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
  }

  var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
  await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
  Stream img = null;
  string filename ="";
  foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
  {
    filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
    img = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    //Do whatever you want with filename and its binaray data.
  }

  bool status = UploadFileToS3(filename, img, "edu-media");

  if (status)
  {
    return Ok();
  }
  else
  {
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
  }
}
```

Note that I am saving my files to `aws s3 buckets` and I don't want `jQuery`, only pure javascript.